# Problema em gerar as parcelas em inputs dinâmicos

Tags: javascript, funções, script

Estou tentando recriar o código abaixo baseado em um que analisei, mas não está funcionando. Acho que tem erro na estrutura! Preciso de uma ajuda.

```
<script>
    function start()
{
    var select_prog = document.getElementById("select_prog"),
    var select_plano = document.getElementById("select_plano"),
    var select_dura = document.getElementById("select_dura"),
        var input_total = document.getElementById("input_total"),
    input_datavenda = document.getElementById("input_datavenda"),
    input_datafinal = document.getElementById("input_datafinal"),
    input_dt_pagto = document.getElementById("input_dt_pagto"),
    input_parcelas = document.getElementById("input_parcelas"),
    input_venc = document.getElementById("input_venc"),
        input_idplano = document.getElementById("select_plano"),
        var select_tp = document.getElementById("select_tp"),
        var select_op = document.getElementById("select_op"),
    select_tp = document.getElementById("select_tp"),
    select_op = document.getElementById("select_op"),
    boletos_set = document.getElementById("boletos_set"),
    din_set = document.getElementById("din_set"),
    chq_set = document.getElementById("chq_set"),
    cde_set = document.getElementById("cde_set"),
    ccd_set = document.getElementById("ccd_set"),
    id_index = 0;
    select_prog.focus();
    select_prog.placeholder = "Selecione";  
    select_prog.onblur = function()
    {
    select_plano.focus();
    select_plano.placeholder = "Selecione"; 
    select_plano.onblur = function()
    {
    select_dura.focus();
    select_dura.placeholder = "Selecione";  
    select_dura.onblur = function()
    {
        input_datavenda.focus();
        input_datavenda.placeholder = "Selecione data"
    }
    input_datavenda.onblur = function()
    {
        input_datafinal.focus();
        input_datafinal.placeholder = "Selecione data"
    }
    input_datafinal.onblur = function()
    {
    input_total.focus();
    input_total.placeholder = "Digite o total";
    input_total.onblur = function()
        {
        select_tp.focus();
        select_tp.onblur = function()
        {
        input_parcelas.focus();
        input_parcelas.onblur = function()
            {
            input_venc.focus();
            input_venc.onblur = function()
            {
            select_op.focus();
            select_op.onchange = function()
                {
                /*Calculo Parcela*/
                var idplano = parseInt(input_idplano.value);
                var tppagto = document.getElementById("select_tp").value;
                var fmpagto = document.getElementById("select_op").value;
                var dt_pagto = document.getElementById("dt_pagto").value;
                input_total = parseFloat(input_total.value);
                input_parcelas = document.getElementById("input_parcelas").value;
                var divisao = parseFloat((input_total / input_parcelas).toFixed(2));
            for(i=0;i<input_parcelas;i++)
            {
            /*Calculo Datas*/
            var s_datavenda = new Date(input_datavenda.value);
            s_datavenda.setUTCDate(s_datavenda.getUTCDate() + (parseInt(input_venc.value)));    
            s_datavenda.setUTCMonth(s_datavenda.getUTCMonth() + id_index);
            var dia = s_datavenda.getUTCDate();
            var mes = s_datavenda.getUTCMonth() + 1;
            var ano = s_datavenda.getUTCFullYear();
            /*Input dinamico com label*/
            var din_input_id_plan = document.createElement("input");
            var din_input_tp_pgto = document.createElement("input");
            var din_input_fm_pgto = document.createElement("input");
            var din_input_dt_venc = document.createElement("input");
            var din_input_parc_num = document.createElement("input");
            var din_input_parc_val = document.createElement("input");
                var din_input_dt_pgto = document.createElement("input");
                var din_input_pago_val = document.createElement("input");
                var din_label_id_plan = document.createElement("Label");
            var din_label_tp_pgto = document.createElement("Label");
            var din_label_fm_pgto = document.createElement("Label");
            var din_label_d_venc = document.createElement("Label");
            var din_label_dt_venc = document.createElement("Label");
            var din_label_parc_num = document.createElement("Label");
            var din_label_parc_val = document.createElement("Label");
                var din_label_dt_pgto = document.createElement("Label");
            var din_label_pago_val = document.createElement("Label");
            id_index++;
                        din_input_id_plan.type = "number";
                        din_input_id_plan.id = "din_input_id_plan" + id_index;
                        din_input_id_plan.value = idplano;  
                        din_input_tp_pgto.type = "text";
                        din_input_tp_pgto.id = "din_input_tp_pgto" + id_index;
                        din_input_tp_pgto.value = tp_pagto;    
                        din_input_parc_num.type = "number";
                        din_input_parc_num.id = "din_input_parc_num" + id_index;
                        din_input_parc_num.value = id_index;
                        din_input_fm_pgto.type = "text";
                        din_input_fm_pgto.id = "din_input_fm_pgto" + id_index;
                        din_input_fm_pgto.value = fm_pagto;           
                        din_input_dt_venc.type = "text";
                        din_input_dt_venc.id = "din_input_dt_venc" + id_index;
                        din_input_dt_venc.value = dia + "/" + mes +"/" + ano;
                        din_input_parc_val.type = "number";
                        din_input_parc_val.id = "din_input_parc_val" + id_index;
                        din_input_parc_val.value = divisao;
                        din_input_dt_pgto.type = "text";
                        din_input_dt_pgto.id = "din_input_dt_pgto" + id_index;
                        din_input_dt_pgto.value = dia + "/" + mes +"/" + ano;
                        din_input_pago_val.type = "number";
                        din_input_pago_val.id = "din_input_pago_val" + id_index;
                        din_input_pago_val.value = divisao;
                        din_label_id_plan.htmlFor = "id_plan"+id_index;
                        din_label_id_plan.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Id Pl"));
                        din_label_tp_pgto.htmlFor = "tp_pgto"+id_index;
                        din_label_tp_pgto.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Tipo Pgto"));
                        din_label_parc_num.htmlFor = "d_venc"+id_index;
                        din_label_parc_num.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Nº parcela"));
                        din_label_fm_pgto.htmlFor = "fm_pgto"+id_index;
                        din_label_fm_pgto.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Forma Pgto"));
                        din_label_dt_venc.htmlFor = "id_venc"+id_index;
                        din_label_dt_venc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Dt Venc"));
                        din_label_parc_val.htmlFor = "d_venc"+id_index;
                        din_label_parc_val.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Valor parcela"));
                        din_label_dt_pgto.htmlFor = "dt_pgto"+id_index;
                        din_label_dt_pgto.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Dt Pagto"));
                        din_label_pago_val.htmlFor = "d_venc"+id_index;
                        din_label_pago_val.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Valor Pago"));
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_id_plan);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_id_plan);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_tp_pgto);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_tp_pgto);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_parc_num);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_parc_num);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_fm_pgto);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_fm_pgto);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_dt_venc);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_dt_venc);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_parc_val);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_parc_val);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_dt_pgto);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_dt_pgto);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_label_pago_val);
                        din_set.appendChild(din_input_pago_val);
                        din_set.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));  
                        }
                     }  
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: O código é bem extenso. Não deixe os leitores a adivinharem qual é o erro, tipo um puzzle. Comece por analisar a janela de inspecionar do navegador que utiliza, que irá dizer-lhe qual o erro e em qual linha. Após perceber qual o erro e em que linha, se não souber como resolver, pode refazer a sua questão face a esse erro, incluindo apenas o código minimo necessário ao problema

Comment: Ok. É o meu primeiro post, uma pergunta que está ha dias está sem resposta!

Comment: E provavelmente irá continuar sem resposta se não melhorar a pergunta. A sua pergunta não tem o html associado para que seja possível testar, não explica também o que está a tentar fazer. Todos esses motivos tornam uma resposta difícil se não mesmo impossível. Tente criar um [exemplo minimo verificavel do problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reveja também o guia de [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Entendi os requisitos. Cuidarei para que atenda.